# Sniffing internal activity - IPC or shared memory?

Tags: ipc, shared-memory, openedge, packet-capture

I have a Progress OpenEdge server, and I want to use a packet-analyzing tool we have to follow what users on the server are doing inside the database. I can see the HTTP traffic from the web management tool, I can see TCP traffic I run remotely, but OpenEdge has got a whole bunch of utilities that can be used for all kinds of administrative duties and are just not getting picked up.

I tried a test run with one of the utilities and recording it with **tcpdump -i lo** but I saw nothing.
I tried **netstat --unix -p** and didn't see any PID advance every time I ran the same utility. 
I tried **ipcs -pm** while test running and saw the LPID change while a CPID stayed the same. So it looks like the same process is catching a shared memory space and attaching/detaching new processes to it. Possibly the process which runs the utility.

Could I have done something more to pin-point the process to shared memory? Is there possibly a chance that this is an IPC process instead?

Comment: Things going on inside the db itself wont show on the network. That resides in memory and on disk. Traffic between the servers and clients should be traceable on the network.

Answer (score 0):

To see what users are doing "inside the database" you will need to do something else.

To see the data access statements use the "client statement cache" feature.  This is available via PROMON under the R&D, Status, 18 menu.  Or via the _connect "virtual system table".

There are many other VSTs that can provide detailed information about the db internals but it is a very broad topic.